# AngularJs - Integratable or dynamic modules

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

The requirement is to have my AngularJs application or product split into different sub products. Depending on the license, we will integrate the sub product in the main product e.g.

```
MainApplication or MainProduct
    |
    --- Core Application  (default)
    --- Free Module2  (default)
    --- Free Module3  (default)
    --- Paid Module4  (module4)
    --- Paid Module5  (module5)
```

The application/product is packaged / deployed in a war

1. A `default` build will package core module1, module2 & module3.
2. A build with parameter `module4` will package core module1, module2, module3 and module4 not module5
3. A build with parameter `module5` will package core module1, module2, module3 and module5 not module4
4. A build with parameter `module4 module5` will package everything.

I am not sure if this is possible. Any suggestion / pointers is welcome.

**Update**
It appears requirejs or oclazyload may help to achieve something similar. 
The main reason of posting this question is to see views of the experts and how people have approached to this.

**P.S**
I am already following the styleguide for large applications within the sub projects.

Answer (score 1):

[This style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) is considered the de-facto standard for structuring AngularJS applications. It goes fairly in depth on how to position your files, so check it out!

Comment: Hi Jaron, I am following the style of angular-seed project within my sub projects. Here, what  i am looking for is integratable projects e.g.

Say some feature is available only to the customer with pro license, so I can build them a pro version and deliver

Comment: Sure that makes sense. If you follow the way of structuring the projects it will lead you to be able to accomplish that easily, however you're really trying to solve a different problem.

You are going to need to setup some sort of authentication/authorization system and only allow paid members access to certain features. How you do that is up to you, however I would recommend using OAuth in some fashion.

Comment: Yes, what you suggest is one way of addressing the problem (I agree it is better) .